# ag-grid context menu icon custom method

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a simple context menu on an ag-grid, `Alert`, which when clicked calls a method `alertOne()`

```
getContextMenuItems(params: GetContextMenuItemsParams): (string | MenuItemDef)[] {
    var result: (string | MenuItemDef)[] = [
      {
        // custom item
        name: 'Alert ',
        action: () => {
          this.alertOne(params.value);
        }
      }      
    ];
    return result;
  }
}

alertOne(value: string) {
    window.alert('Alerting about ' + value);
}
```

I want to add an icon on the above Alert menu item, however when clicks, calls a new method `alertTwo();` so would look like this on the UI:

```
----------------------
|  Alert        (:D) |
----------------------
```

With the above, if the users clicks on the text Alert, `alertOne()` is called. If the `(:D)` icon is clicked, `alertTwo()` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/7T9XiEU4F2RSnqfJ?open=main.js&preview

Right click a cell to get the context menu.  The top menu option has an icon and some text.  Clicking the icon or the text should produce different alerts.

This is achieved like this:

```
function getContextMenuItems(params) {
  var result = [
    {
      // custom item
      name: 'Click for an alert',
      action: () => {
        alert('Main text clicked');
      },
      icon:
        '<img src="https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/skills/windows.png" onclick="clickIcon();" />',
    }
  ];

  return result;
}

function clickIcon(e) {
  alert('Clicked the icon');
  event.stopPropagation(); // If you want both alerts to show, remove this line
}
```

Let me know how you get on

Comment: thanks, when i open the plunkr, the code loads.. but cant see the actual grid, that supposed to happen?

Comment: Sorry, the preview pane wasn't showing.  I've updated the link